# How to keep modal window open after form submit and display new page in same modal window

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Ive got a simple html page with a link that opens a modal window.
In the modal window is a form.
How do I submit the form and display the " form action (test.asp)" page in the same modal window. The test.asp page being the database entry/thank you for filling in the form page.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<style>
#overlay {
 visibility: hidden; position: absolute; left: 0px;top: 0px; width:100%; height:100%; text-align:center; z-index: 1000;
}

#overlay div {width:300px; margin: 100px auto; background-color: #fff; border:1px solid #000; padding:15px; text-align:center;
}
</style>
<script>
function overlay() {
el = document.getElementById("overlay");
el.style.visibility = (el.style.visibility == "visible") ? "hidden" : "visible";    
}           
</script>

<body>
<a href='#' onclick='overlay()'>Click here to show the overlay</a>
<div id="overlay">
<div>
      <p>Please complete the form below.</p>

      <form action="test.asp" method="post" id="contact-form">
        <input type="text" name="field1"><br>
        <input type="text" name="field2"><br>
        <input type="submit" value="Go">
    </form><br>
    Click here to [<a href='#' onclick='overlay()'>close</a>]<br>
 </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You should use AJAX here and overwrite the content of the modal once the form is submitted successfully.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using the javascript function `event.preventDefault()` to prevent a modal closing:

```js
function overlay() {
    el = document.getElementById("overlay");

    el.style.visibility =
        (el.style.visibility == "visible" ? "hidden" : "visible");

    document.getElementById("submit").addEventListener("click",
        function(event){
            event.preventDefault();
        }
    );     
}
```

```css
#overlay {
    visibility: hidden; position: absolute; left: 0px; top: 0px;
    width: 100%; height: 100%; text-align:center; z-index: 1000;
}

#overlay div {
    width: 300px; margin: 100px auto; background-color: #fff;
    border: 1px solid #000; padding: 15px; text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
<a href='#' onclick='overlay()'>Click here to show the overlay</a>
<div id="overlay">
    <div>
        <p>Please complete the form below.</p>

        <form action="test.asp" method="post" id="contact-form">
            <input type="text" name="field1"><br>
            <input type="text" name="field2"><br>
            <input type="submit" id="submit" value="Go">
        </form><br>
        Click here to [<a href='#' onclick='overlay()'>close</a>]<br>
    </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

After that, make an AJAX request using Jquery for next page load in same window:

```
$.ajax({
    url: '/path/to/file',
    type: 'default GET (Other values: POST)',
    dataType: 'default: Intelligent Guess (Other values: xml, json, script, html)',
    data: {param1: 'value1'},
}).done(function() {
    console.log("success");
}).fail(function() {
    console.log("error");
}).always(function() {
    console.log("complete");
});
```